# react dynamic import using a variable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic-import

With React, can anyone explain me why the dynamic import fail when we use a variable ?

```js
// Do not work
let module = "./DynamicComponent";
import(module).then(ModuleLoaded => {})
```

```js
// Works
import("./DynamicComponent").then(ModuleLoaded => {})
```

I tried to refresh the browser cache but nothing change.

Comment: You using CRA Or your custom webpack config? Seems fine to me and it should work. Its JS and nothing seems related to React based on the code you posted.

Comment: I am using the webpack-dev-server by the react-scripts start from create-react-app utils

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per *webpack* documentation.

> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as
> import(foo). Because foo could potentially be any path to any file in
> your system or project.
>
> The import() must contain at least some information about where the
> module is located.

https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import.

**So the below snippet works**

```
import("./components/About").then(component => {
  console.log(component, "loaded successfully");
});
```

**The below snippet doesn't work**

```
let a = "./components/About";
    import(a).then(component => {
      console.log(component, "loaded successfully");
    });
```

I can't find an explanation anywhere that states the exact reason, why the above code works. But my intuition is webpack is not aware of the data type of variable `a` (It has to be a string) hence not able to use it in a dynamic import.

**The above code is transpiled to**

```
let a = "./components/About";
    __webpack_require__("./src lazy recursive")(a).then(component => {
      console.log(component, "loaded successfully");
    });
```

**The below code actually works** (Embedding the variable inside a string literal)..

```
let a = "./components/About";
    import(`${a}`).then(component => {
      console.log(component, "loaded successfully");
    });
```

**And this gets transpiled to**

```
let a = "./components/About";
    __webpack_require__("./src lazy recursive ^.*$")("".concat(a)).then(component => {
      console.log(component, "loaded successfully");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @nithin. I would have never thinking about embedding the variable.

Comment: Embedding the variable inside a string literal does not work for me. Is there anything  else I have to take care of?

Comment: Same for me, even if I embed the variable it is not working. I am using a React framework.

Comment: Where does *"lazy recursive"* comes from and why is it related to this discussion?