# React lazy import statement can't handle expression

Tags: reactjs, reflection

So following dynamic loading works fine:

```
return React.lazy(() => import("./hotels/components/" + componentName));
```

Following does not work:

```
const path = "./hotels/components/";
return React.lazy(() => import(path + componentName));
```

Now i think it might have something to do with the minifier since in the case where it works "import" turns blue in vscode. In case where it doesn't work "import" is yellow.

Also when i compile for the case where it doesn't work i get following warning:

```
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Has anyone ran into this issue?

I tried everything from this similar question:

[Webpack - Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908116/webpack-critical-dependency-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack - Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908116/webpack-critical-dependency-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression)

Comment: @Viet Dinh It did not work

Comment: This may help you, refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349959/react-dynamic-import-using-a-variable-doesnt-work).

Comment: @Eric yes this worked thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following solved the error and got rid of the warning. Just had to embed variable.

```
return React.lazy(() => import(`${path + componentName}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situatuion with TypeScript i had to do separate function in getComponent.ts

src -> Utils -> getComponent.ts

```js
import React, { lazy } from 'react';

type Component = React.LazyExoticComponent<React.ComponentType<any>>;
const componentCache: Record<string, Component> = {};

/**
 * Retrieves a component based on a relative path from the ./src/ directory.
 *
 * @param {string} path - Relative path from the ./src/ directory.
 * @param {string} name - Component name.
 */
export default function getComponent(path: string, name: string): any {
    if (!componentCache[name]) {
        componentCache[name] = lazy(() => import(`../${path}`));
    }

    return componentCache[name];
}
```

And we can use it like that:

```js
 {tabs.map((el, index) => (
    <Box key={index}>
        <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            {React.createElement(
                getComponent(el.componentSrc, el.componentName)
            )}
        </React.Suspense>
    </Box>
))}
```

Data in tabs

```js
export const importerTabs: any[] = [
    {
        componentName: 'FirstCompoent',
        componentSrc: 'Pages/FirstPage/FirstCompoent',
    },
    {
        componentName: 'SecondComponent',
        componentSrc: 'Pages/SecondPage/SecondComponent',
    }
];
```